# Import fonts into JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to import fonts into CSS file into JSF page.

This code works fine:

```
   src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(../fonts/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
```

But this is not working:

```
src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url("#{resource['fonts/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2']}") format('woff2');
```

Any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: I gather that you actually mean to tell that it returned a 404 response when you said "it's not working"? If so, how exactly are you sure that it shouldn't have returned a 404?

Comment: The result is missing font style - I see basic text.

Comment: Elaborate problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. For `#{resource}` to work, the file must of course be placed in `/resources` folder. Otherwise it will return a 404. You have nowhere confirmed that. Why exactly are you otherwise trying to use `#{resource}`?